# How to pass array of dozens of floats to OpenGL 3.0 vertex shader?

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl, vertex, vertex-attribute

I use PyOpengl and Python 3.

I have 50 thousand vertices. Position of each vertex could be calculated in vertex shader as

```
#version 300 es

uniform v_coefficients_weights[COEFFICIENTS_AMOUNT];
in vec3 v_coefficients[COEFFICIENTS_AMOUNT];
in vec3 v_initial_position;
out vec3 v_position;

void main() {
    v_position = v_initial_position + v_coefficients * coefficients_weights;
}
```

Amount of coefficients varies between 0 and 199 — it's not a problem  for me to generate 200 vertex shaders to cover each situation.
I need to change position of vertices tens of thousands times per application calls as fast as it's possible, so I cannot calculate them once on start.

Though, I cannot provide arrays for each vertex because documentation says:

> Attribute variables cannot be declared as arrays or structures.

I see following solutions of this issue:

- (will **not** work) hardcode suffices of variables names to emulate arrays:

  - use vectors with names like coefficients_000, coefficients_001, ..., coefficients_199;
  - use matrices to have 4 vectors in each of variable — will it be better than previous solution with vectors (maybe performance of matrices product is faster than 4 products of vectors)?
- calculate vertices positions by myself using C/NumPy;
- calculate vertices positions by myself in parallel using OpenCL;
- (will **not** work) store all coefficients in `uniform int v_coefficients[COEFFICIENTS_AMOUNT*VERTICES_AMOUNT]` and access needed ones according to vertex number, which will be stored in `in int vertex_id`;
- store coefficients in textures (proposed by @HolyBlackCat).

Are there any other solutions of my issue? Is there optimal solution in proposed above?
Will I go out of memory if I will use 200 float 3-vectors for each vertex?

I imagine the solution with hardcoded indices as:

```
#version 300 es

uniform v_coefficients_weights[COEFFICIENTS_AMOUNT];

in vec3 v_coefficients_000;
in vec3 v_coefficients_001;
...
in vec3 v_coefficients_199;

in vec3 v_initial_position;
out vec3 v_position;

void main() {
    v_position = v_initial_position
        + v_coefficients[0] * coefficients_weights_000
        + v_coefficients[1] * coefficients_weights_001
        + ...
        + v_coefficients[199] * coefficients_weights_199;
}
```

Comment: What exactly you're trying to achieve with that code? How often the coefficients change? If coefficients don't change often, I'd precompute all vertex positions on the CPU.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat coefficients are being changed tens of thousands times per application call and I try to do this as fast as it's possible. Now I'm calculating this using C functions and it takes 40 minutes, which is too slow for me. Thanks for help in specifying my question!

Comment: Ok, more questions. Are coefficients different for each vertex? Also, why exactly you need those computations? (What you're trying to achieve?)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I have only uniform *coefficients_weights* array. Other coefficients are different for each vertex. I use a model of face http://faces.cs.unibas.ch/bfm/?nav=1-0&id=basel_face_model. Uniform coefficients weights are parameters of the model, while coefficients themselves are constant numbers. I try to find best fitting parameters of model for given image using gradient descent algorithm.

Comment: Thanks, now I can understand what do you want. It seems that your idea with hardcoded suffixes might not work on some systems: OpenGL docs say that the minimal value for `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS` is 16. I think you could try to store the coefficients in a texture(s).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes, on my system the limit is 16 both for `GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS` and `GL_MAX_TEXTURE_IMAGE_UNITS`. I guess, I can use global array to store all coefficients and access needed ones by vertex index. Index can be stored as `int` attribute of vertices, but `GL_MAX_VERTEX_UNIFORM_VECTORS` is `4096` on my machine, which is no enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43246/discussion-between-holyblackcat-and-charlie).

Comment: What does this have to do with game development and why would a game developer answer this better than an other type of programmer?

Comment: @MattJensJensen I guess that game developers could face a lot of problems connected with hardware/API limitations and they solve these problems in efficient way

Comment: @Charlie, perhaps but most programmers fall under that category, what I'm getting at is that you have unusual requirements that don't make this look like it's for a game, could you expose a bit more about your desired outcome and what this is for, if this is for a game there is most likely a much better solution to solve the problem that this community will know about, if not, it might be better suited for SO or CG.

Comment: @MattJensJensen I've explained this in comments above. I have a morphable model of Face with ~50 thousand vertices. Model has 200 parameters, which control position of each vertex (and 200 for texture, but now it doesn't matter). I've read that vertex shaders were created to calculate position of each vertex, so it's a good solution for my work except limitations of my hardware. Now 40 thousand renders of the model with calculations on C take a lot of time (~40 minutes), I want to do this as fast as I can to check convergence of chosen algorithms without being very bored.

Comment: @Charlie if your goal is real-time facial animations with game quality realism, then there are far simpler ways to do that without pushing the limits of hardware and software; however if you wish to keep your current method for whatever reason, it becomes much harder to help you with that specific solution.

Comment: @MattJensJensen I want to reconstruct face surface by given photo of human face. In order to do this I need to apply optimization methods, which will find the best fitting model: batch gradient descent, nelder-mead, stochastic gradient descent, genetic algorithm etc. They need the model to be rendered. The faster it will be rendered, the faster I will get results. What methods can be used for facial animation with given model?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks, your advice (about using textures) solved my issue! Could you post your answer to make me able to mark it as right one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solutions appeared to be

- Store coefficients in texture (proposed by @HolyBlackCat). OpenGL allows to save array of `float`s there.
- Calculate all needed values before passing to GPU. I've faced a [performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38941273/how-to-improve-texture-access-performance-in-opengl-shaders) when stored array in texture.